# How to generate executable .jar file for project with multiple packages and libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I am involved in creating a project which has around 60 packages and more than 150 classes and also some external libraries. How can i package these things in to a single executable jar file, so that i can run it as an application. can anyone please provide the detailed steps.

Thanks to the replier in advance.

Comment: Does anyone even search anymore before posting questions? This has been asked many, many times on SO. Possible duplicate of [Executable Jar with depedencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753894/executable-jar-with-depedencies)

Comment: This one is possibly more relevant: [deploying all in one jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212913/netbeans-deploying-all-in-one-jar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse choose 'Export as Runnable JAR'.

If you want it all in one file, choose 'extract libraries into JAR'.

Comment: Thanks Garrett,
Now I am able to generate an executable jar file and it works fine too. but i have one issue. it is working only when placed in the project's workspace and not outside of it. Any ideas would be really greatful.

Comment: Do you have any failure messages?  You can try setting the [classpath when running the JAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) and see if that fixes it.  In that case, you have dependencies in your workspace that are not in the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to mavenize it. Using [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) will help you a lot in the long run with the project describe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbeans, right-click on your project, click on Clean and Build. This will create a folder named `dist` in your project's root directory. That folder contains the `jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven to build your project and generate a jar with all of the dependencies with [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>my-executable</finalName>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <!-- Main class -->
                <mainClass>com.worklight.my.cli.MainClassName
                </mainClass>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```